# JavaScript Pseudoclasses Pattern

Tags: javascript, oop

Hi i'm new to JavaScript and i'm studying Object Creation Patterns, in particular i'm focused on Pseudoclasses Pattern, so i wrote a few lines of code to check if i get the concept:

```
var Car = function (name, x, y) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Car.prototype.drive = function (byX, byY) {
    this.x += byX;
    this.y += byY;
};

var ferrari = new Car("Ferrari", 5, 5);
ferrari.drive(5, 5);

var ferrari_proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(ferrari);
var ferrari_proto_proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(ferrari_proto);
var ferrari_proto_proto_null = Object.getPrototypeOf(ferrari_proto_proto);

console.log(ferrari_proto);                 // Should be Function
console.log(ferrari_proto_proto);           // Should be Object
console.log(ferrari_proto_proto_null);      // Should be Null
```

What i got from running the code is:

```
{ drive: [Function] }
{ }
null
```

and logging the type of these objects i got:

```
object
object
object
```

Now, what i thought was that creating objects this way, the ferrari prototype would have been the Car function, so what i expected was:

```
function    // Tha Car function
object      // The Function prototype, that is Object
object      // null, that is the end of the chain
```

Someone can explain me why i got these outputs and why i was wrong ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the ferrari prototype would have been the Car function

No, your `ferrari`s prototype (the object from which it inherits) is `Car.prototype` - where you put your methods like `.drive`. The `Car` constructor function is different from that.

Comment: I saw in a video tutorial that using the new operator on a constructor function is like adding to lines of code at the beginning and at the end of that function:

    var obj = Object.create(Car);
    ...
    return obj;
if so the new object prototype sould be Car that is a function...right?

Comment: No, the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) uses `Object.create(Car.prototype)`. Either that tutorial was faulty, you misremembered, or they presented a different technique than `new` + constructor functions.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript functions, and arrays are also considered objects. So the log may be returning the base type.

Here is a good resource to understand using JavaScript Prototypes.

http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/12/understanding-prototypes-in-javascript/

Comment: Apart from `createObject = Object.create`, how do you suggest to use this function?